# How to convert Japanese OTF fonts to use with FOP

Tags: fonts, truetype, apache-fop, opentype

I need to generate a Japanese language PDF document formatted with a Japanese font, using Formatting Objects Processor (FOP).  I have a few potential OTF fonts that I would like to use. Unfortunately, FOP does not support OpenType (OTF) fonts with CFF glyph data.  I would like to convert the OTF fonts to a FOP-compatible format.

I have installed FontForge, and I am trying to use it to convert the fonts to TrueType (TTF), but each time, it generates incorrect font files -- or at least the Japanese characters are not converted.

How can have FOP to read my font? In what format do I have to convert them, and maintain the multibyte capabilities?

Note: my English-language setup is working correctly

Comment: You could upgrade to Apache FOP 2.0, which supports CCF OTF fonts: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/releaseNotes_2.0.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to convert the OTF fonts in fontforge:

- Open the OTF font in fontforge
- Use the `Flatten` function in the `CID` menu
- Use `Generate Fonts...` in the `File` menu
- Choose 'TryeType' with the default options

Then use the 'Configuring a font in FOP' described in this page: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/AddFont.html